# Amazon AWS EC2 Instance - Can't connect with SSH

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, debian

This shouldn't be this hard. I cannot connect to new AWS EC2 instance via SSH clients. I am connecting from a Win 7 box.

Instance OS: Debian 6

AMI: `debian-squeeze-i386-20121119-e4554303-3a9d-412e-9604-eae67dde7b76-ami-1977f070.1(ami-a121a6c8)`

User: tried `root` and also `ec2-user`

Using .pem keypair that AWS generated and I downloaded

Confirmed security group and Key Pair Name on instance

SSH port 22 is OPEN: Nmap says so and Telnet gets a welcome reply

Using 3 different clients: all clients connect ok

PuTTY replies: `Server refused our key`

MindTerm Java browser add-in replies: `Authentication failed, permission denied`

Bitvise SSH replies: `Attempting 'publickey' auth; auth failed;`

Rebooted instance, wash, rinse, repeat...

REBUILT new instance and new keypair, wash, rinse, repeat...

Connecting isn't the issue.  Why would the instance not accept the .pem file as the password?  Is there an additional step I am missing?  I followed EVERY frigging guide I could Google.  AWS support is a joke.  stackoverflow to the rescue...

TIA.

Comment: Is anyone using EC2 and Debian 6 together?  Is the user name different?  I read ubuntu instances have a different user name (uh, "ubuntu"), but I tried 'debian' too, no dice...

Comment: Since EC2 allow for third parties to publish AMIs. The username can be whatever the publisher decided to set it. Some cases its root, ec2-user, ubuntu, bitnami, etc.

Comment: see this answer it works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57961330/3904109

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to the [debian wiki](http://wiki.debian.org/Cloud/AmazonEC2Image/Squeeze) which has documentation on the AMI you are using, the username you need to use to login is 'admin'.

Comment: Alpine Linux AMI's are undocumented & have a username of `alpine` - to become `root` after logging in as a `USER` you need to `sudo -s`

Answer (score 1):

I have had many issues with connecting to EC2 via ssh.

```
ssh -i the-keypair-filename root@yourdomain.com
```

- Keypair file must be in same directory.
- I just used terminal to connect.

Make sure you generate or assign the keypair when launching the instance.

Also you can verify the keypair you have set in the AWS Management Console, this is done by selecting the running instance and then looking for "Key Pair Name:".

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: CoderDan, WHERE do I issue that command?  (Assume PuTTY if need be, or tell me your client)  I am connecting from a Win 7 box.  Terminal??

Comment: I am sorry for the delayed response. But I was using mac os x, on windows I assume it would work in the command line

Comment: Great! Missed that I had to assign the keypair while launching the instance and this was causing all the issues for me. Thanks!

Comment: you can also use `ssh -i /path/to/my.pem user@host` from any location

Answer (score 1):

Try using the "admin" username and ignore the username suggested by Amazon.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that I didn't add a volume that was expected in the fstab file so the server didn't start fully and the sshd daemon wasn't running.

Check with:

```
    telnet HOST 22
```

Check the server logs to make sure it starts properly before you waste lots of time like I did.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon Linux AMIs that use ec2-user password are listed at the bottom of this page.

http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/

Check that you are using one of those if trying to use ec2-user, or check the documentation for the AMI you are using.

Teri

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem and I have solved the issue by following approach.

1) Edited the knife.rb file in my chef folder i.e. :\Users\Administrator\chef-starter\chef-repo.chef\knife.rb as bellow:

```
knife[:aws_access_key_id]     = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
knife[:aws_secret_access_key] = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
knife[:region]                = 'ap-southeast-1'
knife[:aws_ssh_key_id] = "ChefUser"
knife[:ssh_user]="ec2-user"
```

In the command prompt, issued the command to create an ec2-server:

```
knife ec2 server create -r "role[webserver]" --image ami-abcd1234 --flavor t1.micro -G  ChefClient -x root -N server01 -i H:\Chef-files\ChefUser.pem
```

Note that, even though I had given all the details in the knife.rb file, I had to give the .pem file path in coomand line through -i option. That solved my problem.

Check, if the solution of mine helps you.

Cheers,

Chandan

Answer (score -3):

Logging in as "ubuntu" worked for me:

**ssh -i private_key.pem ubuntu@myubuntuserver**

Hope this helps

--Erin

Comment: I think the original poster said using Debian, not Ubuntu.