# AWS EC2 closed my port 22

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

i have a problem, im trying to connect to my instance EC2 with SSH, but  say: Connection closed by IP port 22

I was checking all the configuration, im using a Mac with iTerm (also try with terminal) and is not working, looks like AWS EC2 block my Key PEM.

I ask to AWS support, but they said my IP is not block and they dont see any problem...

What I try is open my port 22, enable the remote login, change the permission to my pem.

Also I configure my inbound connection, with the same configuration of another instance and is working.

I was searching for a solution, but I don't have a solution, maybe I can create another instance and move the content to another instance, but I don't know if I can do that?

any information will be helpful

Comment: Looks like a duplicate to [AWS EC2 Connection closed by when trying ssh into instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16992848/aws-ec2-connection-closed-by-when-trying-ssh-into-instance/55150440)

Answer (score 10):

Check that the username was incorrect. On ubuntu instances it should be "ubuntu" and on amazon instances it should be "ec2-user".

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for the following steps in order to connect EC2 from Mac:

1. First download the pem file used / created at the time of instance creation.
2. We have a benefit using Linux / Mac over windows as PEM file created can directly be used to connect. `For windows we need to convert it into PPK file.`
3. Now change the permission of the file to Read / Write and make sure the file extension is .pem and not .txt
4. Check the EC2 permission weather the port is being enabled or not using the following sub steps:

   1. Check the Routes Table for port 22 incoming request is allowed or not.
   2. Check the Network Access Control List of the VPC at the subnet weather the incoming request at port 22 is allowed or not.
   3. Check the Security Group of the instance that weather port 22 request is allowed or not.

> By default all the incoming request is being Blocked by the AWS. And
>   we need to enable the port with the corresponding protocol to allow or
>   not.

If you have no idea then simply you can set the permission to `ALL REQUEST to 0.0.0.0/0`, this will enable to connect your `EC2 to the internet` and to your **ssh** as well.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Step 4.1 - Route table does not operate on a per port basis. Instead step should be check your EC2 instance can route 0.0.0.0/0 traffic to an internet gateway. Check this by looking in the route table that is associated with the subnet your EC2 instance is in. (Within the VPC settings)

Comment: @AlexHague Yes there's no option for setting of port in Routes configuration. We can manage the ports for inbound / outbound rule at Network ACL, Subnet Groups Level.

Comment: yes, that was my point. In step 4.1 you say "Check the Routes Table for port 22 incoming request is allowed or not.". My point is that you cannot check the route table for port 22 incoming requests, as routing works at a lower network layer where port information is not available.

Comment: Yes @AlexHague i meant the same. Routing works at Network Level, and Ports enabling/ disabling are done are TCP/ UDP level of an OSI model.

Answer (score 0):

After many days of struggling with this issue i found solution. You just have to stop your instances and de-attach your volumes and reattach them and it will work like charm. Hope it help you out.