# unable to connect to ec2 instance via SSH (both browser and cli)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have created an EC2 Instance.

I have checked security groups, subnets - inbound traffic and public IP and DNS entry, but still not able to connect it remotely. I am constantly getting following error on accessing it from localmachine and also from trying to connect to it using AWS online ssh content method:

> **Error**: Operation timed out

I have also tried to ping the server, but it also fails.

Can you please help me in connecting remotely with the EC2 Instance?

I am sharing the output of instance describe command so that you can help me. What's wrong with this instance or configuration?

Describe command output:

```
    "Reservations": [
        {
            "Groups": [],
            "Instances": [
                {
                    "AmiLaunchIndex": 0,
                    "ImageId": "ami-0d6621c01e8c2de2c",
                    "InstanceId": "i-0ba33f0cdd3e555fd",
                    "InstanceType": "t2.micro",
                    "KeyName": "jump-key",
                    "LaunchTime": "2020-04-10T05:04:23.000Z",
                    "Monitoring": {
                        "State": "disabled"
                    },
                    "Placement": {
                        "AvailabilityZone": "us-west-2a",
                        "GroupName": "",
                        "Tenancy": "default"
                    },
                    "PrivateDnsName": "ip-10-0-1-250.us-west-2.compute.internal",
                    "PrivateIpAddress": "10.0.1.250",
                    "ProductCodes": [],
                    "PublicDnsName": "ec2-18-236-76-162.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com",
                    "PublicIpAddress": "18.236.76.162",
                    "State": {
                        "Code": 16,
                        "Name": "running"
                    },
                    "StateTransitionReason": "",
                    "SubnetId": "subnet-00532a34e49b7f98f",
                    "VpcId": "vpc-01cd162cf4afcb926",
                    "Architecture": "x86_64",
                    "BlockDeviceMappings": [
                        {
                            "DeviceName": "/dev/xvda",
                            "Ebs": {
                                "AttachTime": "2020-04-10T05:04:24.000Z",
                                "DeleteOnTermination": true,
                                "Status": "attached",
                                "VolumeId": "vol-00907015e8b1b54a4"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "ClientToken": "",
                    "EbsOptimized": false,
                    "EnaSupport": true,
                    "Hypervisor": "xen",
                    "NetworkInterfaces": [
                        {
                            "Association": {
                                "IpOwnerId": "amazon",
                                "PublicDnsName": "ec2-18-236-76-162.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com",
                                "PublicIp": "18.236.76.162"
                            },
                            "Attachment": {
                                "AttachTime": "2020-04-10T05:04:23.000Z",
                                "AttachmentId": "eni-attach-0f18a9b5254184a11",
                                "DeleteOnTermination": true,
                                "DeviceIndex": 0,
                                "Status": "attached"
                            },
                            "Description": "Primary network interface",
                            "Groups": [
                                {
                                    "GroupName": "default",
                                    "GroupId": "sg-0efd8084b6328f481"
                                }
                            ],
                            "Ipv6Addresses": [],
                            "MacAddress": "06:09:8f:cf:5d:e8",
                            "NetworkInterfaceId": "eni-048052fc271148c16",
                            "OwnerId": "811886212371",
                            "PrivateDnsName": "ip-10-0-1-250.us-west-2.compute.internal",
                            "PrivateIpAddress": "10.0.1.250",
                            "PrivateIpAddresses": [
                                {
                                    "Association": {
                                        "IpOwnerId": "amazon",
                                        "PublicDnsName": "ec2-18-236-76-162.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com",
                                        "PublicIp": "18.236.76.162"
                                    },
                                    "Primary": true,
                                    "PrivateDnsName": "ip-10-0-1-250.us-west-2.compute.internal",
                                    "PrivateIpAddress": "10.0.1.250"
                                }
                            ],
                            "SourceDestCheck": true,
                            "Status": "in-use",
                            "SubnetId": "subnet-00532a34e49b7f98f",
                            "VpcId": "vpc-01cd162cf4afcb926",
                            "InterfaceType": "interface"
                        }
                    ],
                    "RootDeviceName": "/dev/xvda",
                    "RootDeviceType": "ebs",
                    "SecurityGroups": [
                        {
                            "GroupName": "default",
                            "GroupId": "sg-0efd8084b6328f481"
                        }
                    ],
                    "SourceDestCheck": true,
                    "VirtualizationType": "hvm",
                    "CpuOptions": {
                        "CoreCount": 1,
                        "ThreadsPerCore": 1
                    },
                    "CapacityReservationSpecification": {
                        "CapacityReservationPreference": "open"
                    },
                    "HibernationOptions": {
                        "Configured": false
                    },
                    "MetadataOptions": {
                        "State": "applied",
                        "HttpTokens": "optional",
                        "HttpPutResponseHopLimit": 1,
                        "HttpEndpoint": "enabled"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "OwnerId": "811886212371",
            "ReservationId": "r-0e1cc9591c1fd51ff"
        }
    ]
}
```

[image: Subnet settings]

[image: Security Group Inbound Settings]

Comment: Did you try to `ssh` from your commandline?

Comment: Yes, but no luck in that too

Comment: I know you said you checked the security group, but just to confirm - did you explicitly allow access to the SSH port (22) for any IP address?

Comment: Can you post the verbose output, `ssh -vvv -i ...`

Comment: Ports Protocol Source default
All All sg-0efd8084b6328f481 ✔  my inbout rules

Comment: $ ssh -vvv -i "jump-key.pem" ec2-user@ec2-18-236-76-162.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
OpenSSH_7.9p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "ec2-18-236-76-162.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to ec2-18-236-76-162.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com [18.236.76.162] port 22.

Comment: debug1: connect to address 18.236.76.162 port 22: Operation timed out
ssh: connect to host ec2-18-236-76-162.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com port 22: Operation timed out

Comment: Your Security Group has only one rule that too is meant to allow aws security group. It does not have a rule to allow your IP address!

Comment: let me add that and try

Comment: i have added traffic from my IP and everywhere, and tried both CLI and AWS Web Connect, but getting connection timeout

Comment: these are the subnet inbout rules: Rule #
Type
Protocol
Port Range / ICMP Type
Source
Allow / Deny
100
ALL Traffic
ALL
ALL
0.0.0.0/0
ALLOW
*
ALL Traffic
ALL
ALL
0.0.0.0/0
DENY

Comment: see this answer it works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57961330/3904109

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The things to check are:

- The EC2 instance is running Linux (Your AMI is Amazon Linux 2, looks good)
- The instance is in a **public subnet**, defined as having its Route Table pointing to an Internet Gateway (Unknown)
- The **security group** permits inbound access on port 22 (Unknown)
- Default **Network ACLs** (Looks good!)
- Connecting via **public IP address** (looks good!)
- Your network allows outbound SSH access (test this by trying an alternative network, such as work vs home vs tethered via your phone)

The *Connection Timeout* is an indication that there is no network connectivity.

In 80% of cases, the cause is the **Security Group** (which you have not shown in your question).

Failing that, I'd say that the instance is probably in a **private subnet**.

Amazon VPC networks are private by default. To connect them to the Internet, you need to attach an **Internet Gateway**. Then, to make a subnet "public", it needs a Route Table configuration that points to the Internet Gateway. Alternatively, you could use the **Default VPC**, which has already been configured with public subnets.

If your Default VPC is not present, it can be recreated via **Create Default VPC** (in the Actions menu).

---

**Update:** Here's the steps to launch a publicly-available Amazon EC2 instance in a new VPC (just to avoid any potential problems with your existing VPC).

- Go to the **VPC management console**
- Click **Launch VPC Wizard**
- The default will create a "VPC with a Single Public Subnet", so click **Select**
- Give it a **Name** and click **Create VPC**
- Go to the **EC2 management console**
- Click **Launch Instance**, then:
- Step 1: Choose **Amazon Linux 2 AMI**
- Step 2: Use defaults
- Step 3: **Auto-assign Public IP:** Enable
- Click **Review and Launch** (leaving everything else at default values)

You will be asked to select a Keypair when launching the instance. Make sure you have the private half of the selected keypair.

Once the instance is **running**, connect to it with:

```
ssh -i keypair.pem ec2-user@IP-ADDRESS
```

If the above works for you, it is then just a matter of comparing the differences between the above configuration and your current configuration. Try to spot what is different, which might be an instance configuration or a VPC/subnet configuration.

If the above does *not* work for you, then it is likely that your network is not permitting the outbound SSH connection. Try it on a different network (eg via a tethered phone) to test this.

Comment: Thank John, I have added the security group settings. and for the reason why again and again, ec2 instances are failing to be connecting remotely, I have shared the detailed instance overview as well.

Comment: I am able to login to ec2 instance by integrating a network gateway to the subnet, to which the ec2 instance is attached? is this is correct way or the only way ? if you know some otherway, without using it, it would be great. I followed the tutorials, but none of them mentioned the internet gateway is required to have the ssh connection from local machine.

Comment: I'm confused by your comment -- are you saying it worked, or are you asking about the setup? I added some more information to my answer. Security is of paramount importance in AWS, so if you created your own VPC, it is private by default.

Comment: no, I used the default VPC and followed several tutorial on connecting the AWS via SSH, but nothing was working. I am asking the question, as I am new to it? does to connect with the ec2 instance via ssh, one need to add the network gateway with the subnet or not? And if there is any other way, with network gateway, please let me know.

Comment: I don't think default VPC public subnets informatoin is correct, I tried it over and over.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein great answer I just wanted to add that I believe the Windows 10 systems now come with ssh enabled by default? Or at the very least require a simple command/settings flip to install and enable so the part about it needing to run Linux may not be entirely true. I use a Windows environment for my dev server and granted I can't remember which one was exactly the case (from my assertions above) but I can ssh into both my command prompt and WSL terminal with no problem

Comment: @Vicky I have added extra steps to my answer showing how to launch an instance in a new VPC. Please try this to see whether it works. If it does, it's then just a matter of comparing what is different with your existing setup.

Comment: I have tried creating a default VPC, but it doesn't create an automatically default VPC and also no subnet is created. According to this document, you will have to create both vpc and subnets and assign an internet gateway for public access https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/default-vpc.html

Comment: @Vicky Please try the instructions I added to my answer. This will create a new VPC so you can test whether everything works. Based on the results of that test, you can then determine what to do next.

Comment: on Action, there is a dropdown manure saying creat default vpc, which says -> Create Default VPC
A default VPC enables you to launch Amazon EC2 resources without having to create and configure your own VPC and subnets. We'll create a default VPC with a default subnet in each Availability Zone, an Internet gateway, and a route table with a route to the Internet gateway, and it it created the vpc, and I have then checked subnets, its there and internet gateway is connected with that. Create VPC button doesn't create default VPC. Please update your answer to help others too. Thank you very much.

Comment: yes, it's working fine, able to connect with web ssh and cli, Thank you very much, I was just lost in the documentation and wondering here and there. Really thank you again.

Comment: You. Are. A life-saver!