# Cant connect to AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

I have a ec2 instance with public ip in public subnet Ubuntu 20.04, everything seems open- But I cant ping or ssh to the instance:

NACL ( I/b & O/b) : 100 - all/all 0.0.0.0/0

Route Table- 0.0.0.0/0  igw

SG: 8080, 443, 22 - 0/0

I have this " **open address** " hyperlink in the ec2 instance console next to public-IP and public DNS - when I try opening it does not open- can't reach this page - tries https://IP.

Putty times out, also cmd ssh:

```
ssh -i "pem-file.pem" ubuntu@IP
ssh: connect to host 'IP' port 22: Connection timed out
```

Comment: Have you setup SSL certs that you try to use HTTPS?

Comment: No I have not setup SSL certs but 443 is open. I am basically trying to ssh with key pair - that itself fails, also ping fails. So probably some connectivity/network issue - I think I have opened everything: SG, NACL, RTB, etc

Comment: port 443 will not work as you don't have ssl. SSHing into the instance also does not work? What exactly is happening? Any errors?

Comment: Putty times out when I try ssh. Also ping fails. Probably the clue is  " open address " hyperlink in the ec2 instance console next to public-IP and public DNS - dont ever recall seeing this anytime

Answer (score 3):

When an SSH connection times-out, it is normally an indication that network traffic is not getting to the Amazon EC2 instance.

Things to check:

- The instance is running **Linux**
- The instance is launched in a **public subnet**, which is defined as having a Route Table entry to points to an Internet Gateway
- The instance has a **public IP address**, which you are using for the connection
- The **Network Access Control Lists** (NACLs) are set to their default "Allow All" values
- A **Security Group** associated with the instance that permits inbound access on port 22 (SSH) either from your IP address, or from the Internet (`0.0.0.0/0`)
- Your **corporate network** permits an outbound SSH connection (try alternate networks, eg home vs work vs tethered to your phone)

See also: [Troubleshooting connecting to your instance - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstancesConnecting.html)

If you continue to have problems, then use `ssh -vvv ...` to activate debugging, and add the output to your Question.

Once you have SSH working, then try to get 443 working.

**Do not use Ping to test connectivity** because that requires additional rules in the Security Group, and all it tests is whether Ping is working.

Comment: It suddenly started working. Did not make any changes to anything. I had tried many things (many times) - restart, terminate/recreate - nothing had worked. One last restart - got a new range public IP 18.x (earlier it was 3.x) - it started working. (I am connecting from personal/home network not corporate).

Answer (score 2):

[**Reachability Analyzer**](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-vpc-insights-analyzes-reachability-and-visibility-in-vpcs/) is an easy solution. It will analyze the requested path and direct you to the problem.

**1. VPC > Reachability Analyzer**

[image]

**2. Create and analyze path**

In this case, I would check the path from the Internet GW to the instance on port 22

[image]

**3. Find the problem**

Once the analysis is completed you can find the issue. In my case it's a routing table with no route to the internet GW

[image]

**4. Fix the problem**

Let's add the needed route
[image]

**5. Verify the path again**

Rerun the analysis again

[image]

**6. SSH is working**

```
     ssh -i "my_key.pem" ec2-user@ec2-900-227-116-41.compute-1.amazonaws.com
       __|  __|_  )
       _|  (     /   Amazon Linux 2022 AMI
      ___|\___|___|  Preview
http://aws.amazon.com/linux/amazon-linux-2022
Last login: Wed Dec  1 09:18:54 2021 from 84.110.59.182
[ec2-user@ip-264-31-83-228 ~]$
```

Comment: see this answer it works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57961330/3904109